# Какой тип нужно указать для e.target.textContent? Свойство "textContent" не существует в типе "EventTarget"

Tags: javascript, typescript, события, typescript-типы

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой тип нужно указать для textContent?

```
const handleOnClickLabel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLLabelElement> = (e) => {
  setOption(e.target.textContent); // Свойство "textContent" не существует в типе "EventTarget".
  setIsActive(false);
};
```

Comment: Вот здесь очень хорошо написано https://freshman.tech/snippets/typescript/fix-value-not-exist-eventtarget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доавьте проверку `if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLElement)) return;` чтоб `ts` правильно тип определил или напрямую тип задайте `setOption((e.target as HTMLElement).textContent)`

```
const handleOnClickLabel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLLabelElement> = (e) => {
    if (!(e.target instanceof HTMLElement)) return;
    setOption((e.target as HTMLElement).textContent);
    setIsActive(false);
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Похожий вариант на ваш, также успешно работает:
`const handleOnClickLabel = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
    const { textContent } = e.target;
    if (textContent) {
      setOption(textContent);
    }
    setIsActive(false);
  };`

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю самый правильный вариант будет таким:

```js
const handleOnClickLabel = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLabelElement>) => {
  setOption(e.target.textContent);
  setIsActive(false);
};
```